# Cannot update msi using vbs

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

Im currently facing problem where the Component GUID of msi are in lower case. Need to convert all the Component GUID to upper case, hence wrote a small script as below:

VBS:

```
msi_fullpath = <Path of msi>

Dim strLine
strLine = "UPDATE Component SET ComponentId = UPPER(ComponentId)"
Set WI = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set DB = WI.OpenDatabase(msi_fullpath, 1)

' Update
Set view = DB.OpenView(strLine)
view.Execute
DB.Commit
View.Close
Set view = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
Set WI = Nothing
```

However the above does not work. Can someone please help?

Comment: How *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: Your SQL command appears suspicious - you haven't specified a specific component, and I don't believe that the command will automatically upcase every component id in the Component table.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers after executing the above VBS the error encountered is Error:OpenView,SQL Code: 80004005, Source : Msi API Error

Comment: @PhilDW the above SQL command is a valid SQL command to update all the rows of a column in UpperCase, have tried it in on a dummy table in SQL Server 2012

Comment: An MSI fle isn't exactly an SQL database, even if there is an SQL interface to (some of) its datastructures. I can't vouch for it, but I don't think `UPPER()` is [valid syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021.aspx) for the Windows Installer database interface.

Comment: @Sujit ... PhilDW is a Windows Installer MVP who wrote the book on MSI.  MSI is from 1999 and supports a "SQL Like"  subset of SQL. It really doesn't care what SQL Server 2012 can do.  Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021(v=vs.85).aspx